# Run xcode in mode debug

Tags: xcode, debugging, xdebug

I am wondering if is possible run xcode in mode debug as you can run Java. I am mean not only for debug your app is more, debug and write code in the same time without re-run the compiler again.

Now each time that I write something new I have to restart the compiler and I lost a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know xcode does not provide a clean native way to do this kind of stuff.

you can try using this project :

http://injectionforxcode.com

I haven't used it intensively yet but it seemed to work pretty well and it is quite easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and remember it right, there used to be some “quickfix” mode in the early Xcode versions that could offer something like this. I’ve never used it, I don’t know how well it worked or why it was discontinued. Nowadays you have to do with the plain edit → compile → run cycle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I am using xcode 5.1.1 but I can't find this option... is still there ?

Comment: No, it was discontinued a long time ago.